# MonadFix in strict language

Tags: haskell, f#, ocaml, monads, monadfix

I'm working on camlp4 extension for haskell-like do notation in Ocaml, and trying to figure out how GHC compiles recursive do-bindings (enabled with -XDoRec).
I wonder if it possible for monadic fixpoint combinator to exist in strict language (like Ocaml/F#/SML/...)?
If yes, how can it look like? Would it be very useful?

Answer (score 14):

The F# computation expression syntax (related to Haskell `do`) supports recursion:

```
let rec ones = seq {
  yield 1
  yield! ones }
```

This is supported because the computation builder has to support `Delay` operation in addition to other monadic (or *MonadPlus*) operations. The code is translated to something like:

```
let rec ones = 
  seq.Combine
    ( seq.Yield(1),
      seq.Delay(fun () -> seq.YieldFrom(ones)) )
```

The type of `Delay` is, in general, `(unit -> M<'T>) -> M<'T>` and the trick is that it wraps a computation with effects (or immediate recursive reference) into a delayed computation that is evaluated on demand.

If you want to learn more about how the mechanism works in F#, then the following two papers are relevant:

- [Syntax Matters: Writing abstract computations in F#](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~tp322/drafts/notations.html)
- [Initializing Mutually Referential Abstract Objects: The Value Recursion Challenge](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=79951)

The first one describes how the F# computation expression syntax is desugared (and how `Delay` is inserted - and in general, how F# combines delayed and eager computations with effects) and the second one describes how F# handles `let rec` declarations with values - like the `ones` value above.

Comment: So, no - it isn't possible in a purely strict fashion. Since all functional languages have some concept of laziness (mostly using functions, closures and variables) - it is possible in "strict languages" via lazy constructs.

Comment: Often the laziness is already there but if your monad is behind an abstract type, OCaml will not let you exploit it -- `This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of 'let rec'`. You need to go for spurious `unit` arguments in such cases (or perhaps "lazy" if you need memoization...)