# mfix for the state monad in OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml, monads, lazy-evaluation, state-monad

How do you implement in **OCaml** the operator

```
mfix : ('a -> 'a state_monad) -> 'a state_monad
```

for a state monad? (Since it relies heavily on laziness, I guess one has to use the Lazy module from the standard library).

---

More precisely:

assuming a signature with

```
type 'a t
( >>= ) : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
```

`mfix` is the least fixpoint of the equation: `mfix f = mfix f >>= f`

But if you define it simply as

```
let rec mfix f = mfix f >>= f
```

you end up with looping recursion due to the strict semantics of OCaml as opposed to the lazy semantics of Haskell.

---

Take for instance

```
type 'a t = 'a list 
let ( >>= ) m f = List.flatten (List.map f m)
```

then for example

```
let _ = mfix (fun _ -> [])
```

leads to a stack overflow while I would like it to be `[]`.

I guess there is a way to overcome this using the Lazy module of the standard library but I cannot find how.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem have you encountered? Have you looked at the implementation of `mfix` for Haskell's `StateT`: `mfix f = StateT $ \s -> mfix $ \ ~(a, _) -> runStateT (f a) s`?

Comment: @Cirdec: Indeed I tried to convert this code into OCaml. But, because of the recursive definition of a, it always end up looping: OCaml is a strict language! I tried to introduce laziness using the Lazy module but it still loops.

Comment: could you please describe what exactly mfix does? It will help OCamlers who don't know Haskell, like myself.

Comment: @JacksonTale: I have added explanations as you required.

Comment: @Bob.  Well values in a CBV language don't work like that.  But I can tell you that `val mfixLazy : ('a Lazy.t -> 'a Lazy.t state_monad) -> 'a state_monad`  and `val mfixThunk : ('a thunk -> 'a thunk state_monad) -> 'a state_monad` where `type 'a thunk = unit -> 'a` are both definable (at least if we're talking about the *lazy* state monad).  You will probably need `val join : 'a thunk thunk -> 'a thunk` and `val fstThunk : ('a, 'b) thunk -> 'a thunk`.

Comment: Related: [MonadFix in strict language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15553526/1333025).